# JavaScript SetTimeout event loop latency problems

Tags: javascript

For example,

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  }, 500);

  let j = i;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(j);
  }, 1000)
}
```

The event loop [loupe](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=DQpmb3IodmFyIGk9MDsgaTwgMztpKyspew0KCXNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24oKXsNCiAgCWNvbnNvbGUubG9nKGkpOw0KICB9LCA1MDApOw0KICBsZXQgaj1pOw0KICBzZXRUaW1lb3V0KGZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7DQogIAljb25zb2xlLmxvZyhqKTsNCiAgfSwgMTAwMCk7DQp9!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D) result:
3 0 3 1 3 2

But in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twf62ybo/) result: 3 3 3 0 1 2

I dont know what cause the two different results and which one would be the correct one.

Comment: 3 3 3 0 1 2 is what's supposed to happen. loupe apparently has a bug.

Comment: Yep, all `i`s should definitely log first, so that's `3 3 3`. Loupe's async visualization probably conflicts with the async nature of `setTimeout`, they need a way to properly pause the script while the animation is ongoing

Comment: umm, I thought the setTimeout would prrint in sequence

Comment: Not if the durations are different...

Comment: The code execution is slowed-down in loupe, so **your** timeouts fire before the actual for-loop executes entirely. Use bigger timeouts and it should work as expected (didn't try myself)

Comment: Got it, thx for explanation

Comment: Please note that the code in your linked "loupe" is different from the JSFiddle code and the code you posted here. In the loupe code, the second timeout is only `100` instead of `1000`, which makes a big difference in this case since one is lower than the first timeout and the other is higher.

Comment: @Lennholm oops, I modified the value and updated the link, and the result still the same